# How to encrypt in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, des, cbc-mode

I'm attempting to perform encryption in Node.js 7.5.0 using the 'des-cbc' algorithm. According to [RFC 1423](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1423.txt), this algorithm requires a 64-bit cryptographic key, and a 64-bit initialization vector.

I'm trying to use a key and iv composed of 8 Latin-1 characters; however, Node is saying, "Error: Invalid IV length". Here's some example code:

```
let crypto = require('crypto');

let key = '\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8',
     iv = '\xb8\xb7\xb6\xb5\xb4\xb3\xb2\xb1';

let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-cbc', Buffer.from(key), Buffer.from(iv));
```

If I change the iv to 8 ASCII characters, then Node is saying, "Error: Invalid key length":

```
let crypto = require('crypto');

let key = '\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8',
     iv = 'abcdefgh';

let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-cbc', Buffer.from(key), Buffer.from(iv));
```

But if both the key and iv are 8 ASCII characters, it works:

```
let crypto = require('crypto');

let key = 'hgfedcba',
     iv = 'abcdefgh';

let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-cbc', Buffer.from(key), Buffer.from(iv));
```

Why can't the Latin-1 characters be used for key and iv?

Comment: You should probably use `Buffer.from(key, "binary")`

Comment: Don't use DES it is not secure, has been superseded by AES and using AES is essentially the same. Also DES does not use the lsb of each byte so `xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8` is really `\xb0\xb2\xb2\xb4\xb4\xb6\xb6\xb8`.

Comment: Or you'd use an array: `const buf = Buffer.from([0x62, 0x75, 0x66, 0x66, 0x65, 0x72]);`. I presume that the current buffer is interpreted as a string instead of a binary array (and I presume that Artjom does to).

Comment: @ArtjomB.: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed. If you add this is an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

You should either use

```
Buffer.from('\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8', 'binary')
```

or even more cleaner as Maarten Bodewes points out

```
Buffer.from([0xb1, 0xb2, 0xb3, 0xb4, 0xb5, 0xb6, 0xb7, 0xb8'])
```

The same goes for your IV.

### Reason

`Buffer.from('\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8').length` results in 16 which is not a valid length for a DES key. DES expects *exactly* 64 bits or 8 bytes as a key. That is also why DES is very insecure. The key size is simply too small.

The reason the above Buffer has a size of 16 bytes instead of 8 bytes is that the default encoding is UTF-8. If a code point is larger than 127 (decimal) or 0x7F (hexadecimal) it will encode into at least two bytes instead of one. Each and every code point (character) of your key is larger than 0x7F. So, each of them is encoded into two bytes.

### Things to think about

**Don't use DES nowadays.** It only provides 56 bit of security. AES would be a much better, because it's more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with DES. See [Security comparison of 3DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).

The IV must be unpredictable (read: random). Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

The key is supposed to be indistinguishable from random noise. It is best to just generate it randomly and use it in your code in encoded form.

It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.